# Reading files in

Tags: java, file, try-catch

I have created a game where there is dogs and cats and dog and cat house on a screen. I have it working great and have a method that randomly places them on the screen, but I would like to let someone be able to use a textfile with coordinates to place them on the screen. So I am trying to create a method to do this.
So I have a folder called levels it has 2 notepad files in it one called level1 and the other called level2. Inside the first file it looks like this.

```
DOG @ 79.0, 409.0
DOG @ 150.0, 320.0
CAT @ 73.0, 194.0
DOG_HOUSE @ 72.0, 158.0
CAT_HOUSE @ 51.0, 591.0
```

the second textfile contains similar things but a little bit different.

```
DOG @ 79.0, 129.0
DOG @ 150.0, 245.0
DOG_HOUSE @ 93.0, 276.0
CAT_HOUSE @ 101.0, 532.0
DOG @ 91.0, 93.
CAT @ 123.0, 294.0
```

The way I create each of these objects is like so. Basically I create the object and then add it to the corresponding array, so then to display the objects on the screen I just have to update each array.

```
 Dogs dog = new Dogs(xvalue,yvalue);
 Cats cat = new Cats(xvalue,yvalue);
 Dog_House doghouse = new Dog_House(xvalue,yvalue);
 Cat_House cathouse = new Cat_House(xvalue,yvalue);
```

Basically they just are the names of the object and then the coordinates as to where they want it to be on the screen. So I need to read in the file, decide which object it is, and create a new object of that kind with the coordinates given. I am guessing it would be easiest to first store each line into a completely new array in this method. Then I should some how do some if statement so that when the scanner sees CAT it will create the object with the coordinates that are on the other side of the @ sign. I guess I could just use some guidance on what I need to put in the while statement to read the lines correctly and to then use that information from that line to create an object.This is what I have so far. Thanks.

```
private boolean loadCustomLevel(String levelFilename) 
{ 

    File inFile = new File(levelFilename);

    Scanner input = null;
    try{
        input = new Scanner (inFile);

        while(input.hasNextLine()){

            }
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.err.println("Error: unable to open file: " + inFile);

    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the way you read the file to this:

```
String input = null;
BufferedReader br = null;

try {
    FileReader file = new FileReader(levelFilename);
    br = new BufferedReader(file);

    while ((input = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(input);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Error: unable to open file");
} finally {
    if (br != null) {
        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {}
    }
}
```

Inside the while loop there are a couple of ways to go. Your current files have different delimiters between values. There is "@", spaces, and commas. One way is you can use the same delimiter so the lines become like this:

```
DOG,79.0,409.0
DOG,150.0,320.0
CAT,73.0,194.0
DOG_HOUSE,72.0,158.0
CAT_HOUSE,51.0,591.0
```

This way you can split each line on a comma and have all of the elements as you want them.

If you want to keep the current format you can use a regular expression to match each line and retrieve each element as a group.

```
// just a starting point
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("^([A-Za-z\\_]+)\\s*\\@\\s*([0-9\\.]+)\\s*\\,\\s*([0-9\\.]+)$").matcher(input);

System.out.println(m.group(1) + " " + m.group(2) + " " + m.group(3));
```

This will return the 3 elements that are needed:

```
DOG 79.0 129.0
DOG 150.0 245.0
DOG_HOUSE 93.0 276.0
CAT_HOUSE 101.0 532.0
DOG 91.0 93.
CAT 123.0 294.0
```

Either way, once you have the elements from each line you can do a switch or an if statement on the first element to decide which object it is, and then proceed accordingly.